# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 't_plate' was corrupted. But where?

Tags: javascript, html, c++

I have already looked around for a solution but i realize that it has to be specific to the code in question.

As you can see i get the error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 't_plate' was corrupted
```

i have also seen the same error around `m` and `t`

I just dont see where it tries to write to the array outside its bounds. I thought i just needed a new set of eyes.

Here is the code in question:

```
// Libs
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Global Vars
char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghij";

int indexOf(char sample[], char find, int start) {
    int index = -1;

    for (int i = start; i < strlen(sample); i++) {
        if (sample[i] == find) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    //cout << strlen(sample) << endl;

    //cout << sample << " - " << find << " - " << index << endl;

    return index;
}

int makehash(string str, int mult) {
    int hash = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        hash = hash * mult + indexOf(alpha, str[i], 0) + 1;
    }

    //cout << str << " - " << hash << endl;

    return hash;

}

int main()
{
    // Get targat hash and hash mult
    int t = 0;
    int m = 0;
    cout << "Target hash: ";
    cin >> t;
    cout << "Hash multiplyer: ";
    cin >> m;

    // Start search and count results

    cout << endl << "-=# Starting search #=-" << endl;

    int r_count = 0;

    int t_plate[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(t_plate); i++) {
        t_plate[i] = 0;
    }

    string c;
    int overflow = 0;
    while (overflow = 0) {
        // create the word
        c = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(t_plate); i++) {
            c += alpha[t_plate[i]];
        }

        if (makehash(c, m) == t) {
            cout << c << endl;
            r_count++;
        }

        t_plate[0]++;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(t_plate); i++) {
            t_plate[i] = t_plate[i] + overflow;
            if (t_plate[i] >(sizeof(alpha) - 1)) {
                t_plate[i] = 0;
                overflow++;
            }
        }

    }

    // End search and print number of results

    cout << "-=# Search ended #=-" << endl;
    cout << "Results found: " << r_count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Yes its a brute-force, its for the Real 3 lvl from https://www.hackthis.co.uk/

It might be really obvious, but i guess I'm blinded by looking at it to long.
If you would like a look at the site/lvl i made the code for, here is the direct link: https://www.hackthis.co.uk/levels/extras/real/3/login.htm
In the console you can find the user-data(hashed) in the obj. `m` and the rest of the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            here
        </script>
        ...
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

Did i forget to include something? Let me know!

Thanks in advance!
Sincerely, Otard95

Comment: `while (overflow = 0)` -> `while (overflow == 0)`

Comment: `sizeof(t_plate)` gives the size in bytes, not in `ints`.

Comment: @BoPersson That's the answer.

Comment: Ok let me try that out! Tanks!

Comment: I didn't know sizeof() gave bytes so learned something there! Tanks again! And the `=` to `==` how did i not catch that *facepalm*. Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: I mean I know it will take like 2000 years to go through all the possibilities but it's fun to make.